# How can I know what element is clicked in IE?

Tags: ruby, watir, win32ole

I'm automating IE with watir, and I want to know what html element(s) are clicked (selected). Can this be done using watir? win32ole? In a last chance, without ruby?

Something like:

```
Click a button -> button with id=213 and class=btn_class was clicked. 
Click a text field -> text field with id=123 and value=my_text was clicked.
```

Comment: In short, you want some debugging information? After you click a link, you want Watir to display (in the command prompt) something like `button with id=213 and class=btn_class was clicked`?

Comment: exactly, with the basic elements like buttons, links, text fields and if it is possible, divs, tables, etc. Actually i'm using IE debugger tools, but i want more control about this information.

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want debugging information when you click a link manually, or when you click it with Watir?

Comment: When clicking a link manually.

Comment: In that case, Watir can not help you.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but with win32ole? or with another programming language more IE friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the recorders, [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand either, but would a custom function like this work?

```
        def click(item, how, what)
           @browser.item(how, what).click
           puts "#{item} with #{how}->#{what} was clicked"
        end

        click("button", ":id", "awesome")
```

**Edit:** If you're attempting to identify page elements so that you can then use them in a Watir script, the Developer Toolbar is perfect for this application, much like Firebug for Firefox.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Your comment to me & your response to Zeljko appear to contradict each other.  If you want to use WATIR for this task, the code above will execute a mouse click and post the information to console.  The only other way to get information is to locate the object in WATIR and fish for more details:

```
object = @browser.button(:name, /myButton/)
object.id
object.title
object.status
object.height, etc.
```

or

```
@browser.divs.each do |div|
    puts div.id, div.title
end
```

Comment: Nope, the click it is "real", with a real mouse.

Comment: Oh. This really has nothing to do with automating IE then - you're just looking for debugging information in Internet Explorer in response to manual interactions.  Have you tried the Developer Toolbar?  It works like Firebug for Firefox in that when you click on an object, it shows you the element you're clicking on in the console and its attributes.  I can't tell if that's what you meant by "IE Debugger tools".

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by "IE debugger tools" i was meant to say that i'm already using the "Developer Toolbar", but i cannot modify this app to have more control about the information of the html elements. I was "supossing" that as Watir have a connection with IE, can extract that information, or with ruby or with another language. In other words: have "that" feature of the IE developer toolbar, but "do" something automated with that information. for example: 1 "real" click an element 2. identify the element and extract the "basic" information. 3 print that information to a plain text file.

Comment: Assuming that a real click refers to a manual mouse click, I do not believe there is a way to interact with Watir like that.  However, as I've provided in the code samples above, you can get all of the other information about an element by first accessing it with the one method you do know, or iterating through all of that type of element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a strong look at the capabilities of the various developer tools, such as are provided with Chrome, Firefox, and IE.   those are generally the best means to get this kind of information.

Watir is really about driving the browser, and getting info out of the DOM.  it's not really setup to report on manual interactions with the browser.